PTFE wear factor
I'm designing a linear actuator made of mild steel that will move back and forth inside a sleeve made of mild steel too.
I would like to use PTFE as the material between them. What are the pros and cons of these two options:

PTFE attached to only one of the surfaces (PTFE vs mild steel friction).
PTFE attached to both surfaces (PTFE vs PTFE friction).

The actuator force is around 5 N, and the gap will be around 0.1 to 0.2 mm. Will the PTFE wear and friction be different in both cases?

So test both - make a rig where you can control speed and load. But if they don't touch by 0.1 or 0.2mm then how do they wear?

Sorry if I haven't been clear regading the 0.1 to 0.2 mm gap. This is the space where the PTFE material will be.

I think you will find that solid PTFE will soon become particles of PTFE under any significant load.  My limited experience with this is particles of PTFE in a carrier lubricant (Break-Free gun lube).  I think that materials combined with PTFE is a potential solution.

You might get some ideas from https://igus.com. They've been making polymer bearings for many decades.

Mild steel can be overplated with teflon/nickel to a thickness of .0002 to .0004 inches which makes a lubricated, durable bearing interface. Usually both the movable and stationary surfaces are thus plated and running clearances kept to a minimum. You will need to find a reputable plater familiar with the process.
